# Flutter NestedScrollView how to disabled scroll header when scroll body

Tags: flutter

How to make a NestedScrollView so that until the ListView (located in the body) scrolls up to the end, the headerSliverBuilder does not start displaying.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet of your problem